# Variable count does not increment in js

Tags: javascript, increment

I'm new to `Js` .I'm trying to use a function called `valider` to increment the variable count whenever the user writes a correct answer in the inputs and show the value of count in a pop up using the Alert.

As you can see , the variable count doesn't increment.

```js
var input1 = document.getElementById("input1").value;
var input2 = document.getElementById("input2").value;
var input3 = document.getElementById("input3").value;
var input4 = document.getElementById("input4").value;
var count = 0;
        
function valider() {
  if(input1 == 6) {
      count += 1;
  }
  if(input2 == 42) {
      count += 1;
  }
  if(input3== 16) {
      count += 1;
  }
  if(input4 == 15) {
      count += 1;
  }
 
  alert("Vous avez " + count + " bonnes réponses");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <label>3*2</label> 
        <input type ="text" id="input1"> <br><br>
        <label>6*7</label> 
        <input type ="text" id="input2"> <br><br>
        <label>4*4</label> 
        <input type ="text" id="input3"> <br><br>
        <label>3*5</label> 
        <input type ="text" id="input4"> <br><br>   
        <button type="submit" onclick="valider()">Valider</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Copy the text, not a screenshot. Whenever the text is indented with 4 spaces, it is shown as code. Or you press the `{}` on a text selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you only get the values of your input once not on every call to `valider`. Just get all the values in your function and it should work:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <label>3*2</label> 
        <input type ="text" id="input1"> <br><br>
        <label>6*7</label> 
        <input type ="text" id="input2"> <br><br>
        <label>4*4</label> 
        <input type ="text" id="input3"> <br><br>
        <label>3*5</label> 
        <input type ="text" id="input4"> <br><br>   
        <button type="submit" onclick="valider()">Valider</button>
    </form>
    

    <script>
        function valider() {
            var input1 = document.getElementById("input1").value;
            var input2 = document.getElementById("input2").value;
            var input3 = document.getElementById("input3").value;
            var input4 = document.getElementById("input4").value;
            var count = 0;

            if(input1 == 6) {
                count += 1;
            }
            if(input2 == 42) {
                count += 1;
            }
            if(input3== 16) {
                count += 1;
            }
            if(input4 == 15) {
                count += 1;
            }
            alert("Vous avez " + count + " bonnes réponses");
        }

    </script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

I also moved the `count` variable inside the function. Otherwise people can enter 1 correct answer and spam the Valider button to increase the count.